# Export multiple outputs within foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm looking to export some data, in particular an AD user along with their AD groups.

My current code:

```
$users = import-csv -path C:\path

    foreach ($user in $users) {
    $user | select name,SamAccountName | ft
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.samaccountname | select name
    #export-csv -path C:\path-NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

The issue i'm having is whenever I try to export this information i'm only exporting the group output whereas I need the username to see who these groups actually belong to.

Perhaps there's a better method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `Select-Object` to sort of "bind" the information together with a couple of calculated properties referencing the current `$user`'s properties:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.samaccountname |Select Name,@{Name='User';Expression={$user.Name}},@{Name='SAMAccountName';Expression={$user.SAMAccountName}} |Export-Csv -Path C:\path -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

If you want to group the output in the shell by user name but only display the group name, you can use `Format-Table Name -GroupBy User`:

```
# collect the information
$groupMemberships = foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.samaccountname |Select Name,@{Name='User';Expression={$user.Name}},@{Name='SAMAccountName';Expression={$user.SAMAccountName}}
}

# format console output 
$groupMemberships |Format-Table Name -GroupBy User

# export
$groupMemberships |Export-Csv -Path C:\path -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I gave it a try but it seems to output it differently from what I'm looking for. Right now it shows 3 Columns `Name`, `User`, `SAMAccountName` but i'm trying to get it to output with the user and then show their AD membership if that makes sense?

Comment: @MatthewMatthew I get what you mean, but then a CSV file is not a good output medium

Comment: could you suggest a better one? I'm new to PowerShell but had assumed CSV was really the best method for these things - always happy to learn!

Comment: @MatthewMatthew I added an example of how to format your console output closer to what you want, while retaining the CSV-friendly data structure

Comment: I wish i could also rate up but this is exactly what I was trying to do, many thanks